# Confusing /calendaring tag?

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

[`/calendaring`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/calendaring)

I'm not quite certain of the relevance of this tag. Does it mean "calendaring software" (in which case `/calendaring-software` should exist)? Or does it refer to the process of calendaring and adding appointments to an agenda.

Why not just have `/calendar`? I can see a lot more questions being of relevance to a `/calendar` tag than a `/calendaring` tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go for it. This is the same case as the oops tag you [mentioned earlier](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/824/can-we-please-change-remove-the-oops-tag) -- a single user created it without putting much thought into it; it only takes [300 rep to create tags](https://unix.stackexchange.com/privileges/create-tags), and they probably only bothered because the system requires at least one tag on a question. When there's only a couple posts with a tag it's easy for anyone ([mostly](https://unix.stackexchange.com/privileges/retag-questions)) to come up with a better tag and retag them more appropriately. If you retag that question [calendar](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/calendar) instead the [calendaring](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/calendaring) tag will get automatically deleted within 24 hours

Comment: Done. I've retagged the question with `/calendar` instead. Thanks Michael.