# Can we please change/remove the /oops tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

[`/oops`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/oops)

Seems ambiguous to me. It has only been used for one question referring to tainted kernels. `/oops` could also be construed to mean object-oriented programming languages.

In the first case, `/oops` is simply a `/kernel-panic` and in the second, `/oops` would be less ambiguous as `/oo-programming` or `/object-oriented-language` (not pretty, I know).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A kernel oops is not *necessarily* a kernel panic. Seems like [kernel-oops](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kernel-oops) would resolve the ambiguity you're concerned about — although I'm skeptical that people would jump to "object-oriented programming languages" (Because: what's **O**bject **O**riented **P**rogramming**s** supposed to mean?)

Maybe someone might use it for `rm -rf /`.....

Comment: I didn't know what a kernel oops was, and when I saw the tag I figured it could be an acronym for object-oriented programming languages. The `rm -rf /` reason is definitely a possibility too.

Comment: Turns out there was just the one question using it. I retagged it [tag:kernel-oops] and there ya go.